# Sum the rows according the columns?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, sum

I have the table which looks:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I need to sum sums according to the dates but there is the thing:

- If there is a new date (b column) then the sum should be assigned to a new date
- If there is no new date (b column) then the sum should be assigned to date (a column).

The total sum should be in the new table:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Is it possible to create this formula in excel or google sheets without macro? It is possible to use if and sumifs in this case?

Thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D8u8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gsAJ.png

Comment: What are the expected values ?

Comment: People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. You can always create a sheet of dummy data that people can access and play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=query(arrayformula(split(flatten(A2:B&"|"&C2:C),"|")),"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'total sum'",0)
```

[image]

### edit

```
=query({arrayformula(if(B2:B="",A2:A,B2:B)),C2:C},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) 'total sum'",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mike, 
I need that if there is value in the new date, then the sum is assigned only to the new date and it doesn’t need to be assigned in date. In your example, A should be equal to 2.

Comment: I have edited my answer